# URL Shortener in python

Tags: python-3.x, url-shortener

For URL Shortening , here i used `Adfly`. but i am getting type error!

```
from pyshorteners import Shortener

url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/url-shorteners-and-its-api-in-python-set-1/?ref=lbp"
ShortenedURL = Shortener('Adfly' , uid ='24352319' , key='07eb7bf58efa292d99437daddea9496b' , type = 'int')
print("Short URL is {}".format(ShortenedURL.short(url)))
```

Error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-fb2e845d42a4> in <module>
      8 
      9 url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/url-shorteners-and-its-api-in-python-set-1/?ref=lbp"
---> 10 ShortenedURL = Shortener('Adfly' , uid ='24352319' , key='07eb7bf58efa292d99437daddea9496b' , type = 'int' )
     11 print("Short URL is {}".format(ShortenedURL.short(url)))
     12 get_ipython().run_line_magic('pinfo', 'Shortener')

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am unable to distinguish the error. please help me.

Comment: The documentation is telling a different story, you are using the function incorrectly : https://pyshorteners.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis.html#adf-ly

Comment: Don't post your API key in a public place.

Comment: @kaya3 this is example key!